# WP_NAV_MENU filter targets all menus

Tags: plugin-development, menus, filters

Im trying to replace my template's primary menu through a plugin so that I don't have to make changes to the header.php.

I found this code in another question answered here in 2011 ([Replacing WordPress menu functionality with a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24354/replacing-wordpress-menu-functionality-with-a-plugin))

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'my_menu_func');
function my_menu_func(){
  print "Testing 123";
}
```

It worked but it replaced both my top primary menu and the widget side menu.

How can I specify which menu to target when using the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code snippet to override the *primary* menu:

```
/**
 * Override the primary menu.
 *
 * @param string  $nav_menu The HTML content for the navigation menu.
 * @param array   $args     Array of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 * @return string $nav_menu
 */

function wpse_150003( $nav_menu, $args )
{
    //Override the primary menu:
    if( 'primary' === $args->theme_location )
        $nav_menu = 'My new menu';

    return $nav_menu;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'wpse_150003', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

where we find the input arguments info from the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L412).

Notice that we **return** the `$nav_menu` value, instead of **echoing** it.

You could also filter my other attributes, for example `menu_id`.

You might also consider these filters:

- `wp_nav_menu_items`
- `wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items`

I hope this helps.